# How to have url not encoded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I don't understand why all my special characters in my url are encoded for example :

```rb
new_subscription_url(:session_id => '{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}' )
```

Give me

```
http://localhost:3000/en/subscriptions/new?session_id=%7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID%7D
```

All special characters are encode. How could I have them not encoded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not encoded but rather escaped.
According to Internet standard ([IETF](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) section 2.4), URI is always in an "escaped" form.
On the side note, if you want to unescape it, you can use

```
CGI::unescape(new_subscription_url(session_id: '{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}' ))
```